# why does decrementing by 0.1 within for loop produce this undesired result in lua

Tags: lua

```
j=1
for i=1,10 do 
    j=j-0.1
    print(j)
end
```

**the output is:**

0.9
0.8
0.7
0.6
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.1
1.3877787807814e-16

where the last entry should be 0
Note: 0.1-0.1 returns 0.0
but, repeatedly doing j=j-0.1 from j>=0.3 produces this result

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in lua are doubles which is [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), floating-point numbers has [floating precision error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation). In fact `0.1` is not exactly `0.1`, it's the closest representation of `0.1`.

Possible fix would be probably using integers or integer with separate decimal part.
Related question with answer: [C++ How to avoid floating-point arithmetic error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859875/c-how-to-avoid-floating-point-arithmetic-error)

Answer (score 0):

round off error!

0.1 cannot be represented exactly in IEEE 64 bit floating point
1/10 has a recurring representation in binary!